# « Farfelu » est-il courant, depuis quand ?

Tags: sens, évolution

J'ai rencontré l'adjectif farfelu dans un ouvrage scientifique canadien :

> Bien qu'elle soit séduisante l'idée d'un point de vue énergétique, la
>   voiture nucléaire est une idée farfelue.

1) Je me demande pourquoi ce mot n'existe pas dans le dictionnaire Le Littré (la version disponible  hors ligne pour Windows au moins).

2) Peut-on employer cet adjectif en français courant ?

Comment: Le mot se trouve chez Littré mais sous la forme plus ancienne de "fafelu".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

D'après le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/farfelu), le mot date de 1921, alors que le Littré date du XIXème siècle. C'est un vieux dictionnaire et il n'y a pas de raison de croire qu'il contient tous les mots employés dans le langage courant au XXIème siècle.

Oui, on peut très bien l'utiliser dans le langage courant. Tout le monde comprendra, ce n'est pas un mot obscur. (En France en tout cas.)

Comment: Le dictionnaire en ligne Larousse est préférable pour les mots courants: http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/farfelu

Answer (score 1):

On trouve *farfelu* sous la forme *fafelu* chez Mme de Sévigné dans une lettre à sa fille du 19 février 1690.  C'est en fait son fils Charles qui utilise *fafelu* puisque c'est lui qui rédige une partie de la lettre pour s'adresser à sa sœur :

- J'embrasse mais chrétiennement et en oncle, la jolie infante [c'est sa nièce], qui me fait souvenir de cette jolie infante [sa sœur] éveillée et **fafelue**, qui était à la portière du carrosse de sa mère…

*Fafelue* fait l'objet d'un appel de note de la part de Roger Duchêne, l'éditeur de la correspondance de Mme de Sévigné dans la Bibliothèque de la Pléiade :

- *fafelue*, signalé par Oudot et Cotgrave, existe dans l'ancien français au sens de gros et dodu, sens préférable, selon Godefroy, à celui d'espiègle proposé par Littré.

Le dictionnaire (1611) de Cotgrave (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randle_Cotgrave) donne pour *fafelu*, *puffed up*, *fat cheeked* et pour *farfelu*, *short and thick*, *as thick as long*.

Frédéric Godefroy, dans son monumental *Dictionnaire de l’ancienne langue française du ixe siècle au xve siècle* (1891-1902) définit *fafelu* par *gros et dodu*.  Il précise, « ce mot vieilli a été employé par Mme de Sévigné, non pas, comme dit Littré, dans le sens d'espiègle, mais bien dans le sens de dodu. »

Le TLFi fait remonter à 1921 et à André Malraux la relance de *farfelu* dans le sens de fantaisiste.  Malraux travaillait en 1919 et 1920 pour René-Louis Doyon, bouquiniste et éditeur clandestin d'ouvrages licencieux.  En 1920 sort aux Editions de la Connaissance dirigées par Doyon une petite plaquette intitulée *Douze épigrammes plaisantes imitées de P.-V. Martial, chevalier romain, par un humaniste facétieux* dont l'auteur est Georges Fourest.  Pascal Pia, ami très proche de Malraux en ce temps-là, fournit la précision suivante à propos de ce livre :

- L'achevé d'imprimer dit : Tiré à deux cents exemplaires sur les presses de Flavius Niger et Cie, imprimeurs-jurés, 69, rue du Satyre-**Farfelu**, 69, à Phalopolis-en-Lanternois Anno Domini MCMXX.  *Pia ajoute* : Petit recueil d'épigrammes dues à Georges Fourest, et publiées par les Editions de la Connaissance, que dirigeait René-Louis Doyon.  On sait qu'André Malraux était en 1920 un des habitués de la librairie qu'exploitaient, Galerie de la Madeleine, à Paris, les Editions de la Connaissance.  Son influence se sera probablement exercée dans le choix de la rue du Satyre-**Farfelu** pour lieu d'impression supposé de cette plaquette.

*Farfelu* associé à *satyre* conserve ici encore le sens de gros, dodu, *as thick as long*; il a une connotation sexuelle évidente.  C'est un mot qui semblait beaucoup plaire au jeune Malraux qui devait l'avoir rencontré chez les écrivains aux mœurs libres du xvie siècle, qu'il fréquentait et connaissait  très bien.

Comment: Malraux *fréquentait* les écrivains du XVIe siècle ? ;-)

Comment: @jiliagre   Bien sûr!  Pas vous?  Ils sont d'un commerce très agréable et instructif.

Comment: Ma DeLorean est en panne...

Answer (score 0):

- Complément :

> L'étymologie de ce mot reste très contestée ; il peut se rapprocher de
> berlue, qui lui même propose un radical celtique belo, qui signifie
> étincelant, et un radical gascon belet, qui signifie éclair. Si le mot
> berlue est à l'origine de farfelu, on peut y voir un rapport avec la
> lumière (étincelant, éclair) confirmé par le suffixe lu, préfixe des
> mots lumière, luciole, lucide. Alain Rey fournit une hypothèse de
> croisement de l'ancien français fanfellue ou fafellue (sottise) avec
> le radical expressif faff- trouvé dans des mots désignant des choses
> vaines ou trompeuses (fafiot). fanfellue lui-même vient par le latin
> fanfaluca du grec phompholux (bulle d'air). L'altération en farfelu
> viendrait de l'influence d'autre mots en far- (farfouiller, faribole).
> Le mot farfelu lui même, utilisé au XVIe siècle, renvoyait à dodu, et
> depuis le XXe siècle, à fou, qui peut varier en fafelu. Source : https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition-farfelu/

- On retrouve le mot farfelu dans un autre lemme (mot cervelas) du dictionnaire Littré : https://www.littre.org/definition/cervelas

> XVIe s. Ung groz cervelat saulvaige et farfelu… et trencha le cervelat
> en deux pieces, vray dieu que il estoit graz ! Rabelais, Pant. IV, 41.

- Le mot se trouve chez Littré mais sous la forme plus ancienne de "fafelu". – (thanks @petitrien)